# jQuery AJAX - variable in ajax is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have following code:

```
function updateValue(type, id, updatedValue)
{
    // result bellow is 1200-1200
    console.log(updatedValue + "-" + encodeURIComponent(updatedValue));
    if (type >= 1 && type <= 3)
    {
        $(document).keypress(function(e) 
        {
            if (e.which == 13) 
            {
                // result below is: loader/updateinfo.php?type=1&value=&by=26
                console.log("loader/updateinfo.php?type=" + encodeURIComponent(type) +"&value=" + encodeURIComponent(updatedValue) + "&by=" +encodeURIComponent(id));
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "loader/updateinfo.php",
                    data: {type: encodeURIComponent(type), value: encodeURIComponent(updatedValue), by: encodeURIComponent(id)},
                    success: function(result) 
                    {
                        window.console.log('Successful ' + encodeURIComponent(id));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in code, at the start of the function, value of variable updatedValue is correct, but above ajax - as well as in ajax, the value is empty. How is that possible and what could cause it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

can u please remove the document keypress and check.If u want keypress function put into the first line. If you want more reliable ans please share the javascript file and when u are calling the updatevalue function

Comment: You are right, it causes that the document keypress. If I remove it, it works.. But if I put it at the start of the function, it does not work as well. Where is problem?

Comment: $(document).on("keypress", function(){

 if (e.which == 13) {

function updateValue(type, id, updatedValue){
 if (type >= 1 && type <= 3) {
//call the ajax method here

}

}}

});
If you want set the value for type , id , updatedValue then make its as global variable